# What kind of coordinate system has values like 555,19 - 251,48?

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, france

I am trying to identify a coordinate system used to give positions to caves in France.

The Emergence du Ressel is at 555,19 - 251,48 (decimal coordinates 44.56194, 1.77167) and Source de Landenouse is at 562,54 - 243,17 (decimal coordinates 44.48763, 1.8657).

I am unable to identify the (xxx,yy - xxx,yy) coordinate system.  How do I convert from that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could be wrong but I think they are in Lambert system.  Check out this tutorial as it explains conversions and it deals with caves in france, so i would think its what you are looking for

http://takenfromhere.co.uk/coordinate-conversion/

Comment: That was it! Go to http://geofree.fr/gf/coordinateConv_EN.asp, multiply the coordinates with 1000, and select Lambert III (France sud). Voila!